# navigation doesn't work in custom header.php

Tags: navigation, headers, directory, custom-header

I've made a custom `header-blog.php`(for blog page/`home.php`) in addition to `header.php`, both of which use the exact same `<nav>` code. On the pages that use `header.php`, the navigation works perfectly. However, on the blog page(`home.php`), which uses `header-blog.php`, the navigation doesn't work- all links lead to "Nothing found."

What could be the cause of this? How can I fix it? This is my first time with something like this, so any insight and ideas are greatly appreciated.

header-blog.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Wordpress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback url'); ?>" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/favicon.ico" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>



<body>
    <div id="blog-header">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="Urban Palate logo" id="logo" /></a>
        </div><!-- end logo -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="?page_id=7"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/about.png" alt="Urban Palate intro" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="?page_id=12"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/portfolio.png" alt="Urban Palate portfolio" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="?page_id=15"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/blog.png" alt="Urban Palate blog" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="?page_id=10"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/contact.png" alt="Urban Palate contact" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div><!-- end blog-header -->
```

Comment: What does the url look like that is not found VS the url that it should be pointing to?

Comment: This appears in the address bar: http://urbanpalate.com/blog/?page_id=12

After clicking this link: `<li><a href="?page_id=12"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/portfolio.png" alt="Urban Palate portfolio" /></a></li>`

Comment: @Ben any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm mostly thinking that you should maybe switch to using wp_nav_menu() for your navigation menus, and CSS to add the images to your nav items, because it's a lot more dynamic that way, and you can use "pretty" permalinks like http://urbanpalate.com/portfolio/some-work.

As it stands though, I think your nav menu items just need a / at the beginning of the urls like this:

```
<a href="/?page_id=12"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/portfolio.png" alt="Urban Palate portfolio" /></a></li>
```

That would take you to http://urbanpalate.com/?page_id=12, which I hope would load your portfolio page. The / means it's an absolute url: or, start at your home url, and go to a page. Without the /, your nav items are pointing to pages under the blog page because they are relative to which page you are on.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your time and efforts.
I'll look in to making the switch to `wp_nav_menu()`.